# Como pegar o valor de um atributo em JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

É o seguinte: preciso fazer com que quando uma pessoa clicar sobre uma imagem, o atributo 'display' de um 'ul' seja mudado para block, e depois, quando essa pessoa clicar novamente, o valor do atributo seja 'none'. Eu queria pegar o valor do atributo 'display' dessa lista para fazer com que se o valor for 'block', quando ela clicar no 'ul' o valor seja 'none' e ele suma.

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Teste</title>
</head>
<body>

    <img src="../imagem.png" id="imagem"/>

    <ul id="lista">
    <li>Item de lista</li>
    </ul>

</body>
```

**JQuery**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
            $("ul#lista").css('display', 'none');

            $("img#imagem").click(function() {
                $("#listadostres").css('display', 'block');
            })
            })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para fazer o efeito de sumir/aparecer você pode usar o `.toggle()` do jquery:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("ul#lista").css('display', 'none');

  $("img#imagem").click(function() {
    $("#lista").toggle();
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Teste</title>
</head>

<body>

  <img src="http://www.gper.com.br/noticias/2eb16ca9ded57e738bac82f73e5a7a6f.jpg" id="imagem" style="height: 80px"/>

  <ul id="lista">
    <li>Item de lista</li>
  </ul>


</body>
```

Já para captura o valor do css, basta não passar o segundo argumento na função `.css()`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("ul#lista").css('display', 'none');

  $("img#imagem").click(function() {
    if($("#lista").css('display') == "none"){
      $("#lista").css('display', 'block')   
    }else{
      $("#lista").css('display', 'none')   
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Teste</title>
</head>

<body>

  <img src="http://www.gper.com.br/noticias/2eb16ca9ded57e738bac82f73e5a7a6f.jpg" id="imagem" style="height: 80px"/>

  <ul id="lista">
    <li>Item de lista</li>
  </ul>


</body>
```

Comment: Deu certo! Valeu, cara, vou marcar como resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Veja o exemplo abaixo funcionando, utilizando o método `is` e o parâmetro `:visible`:

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#lista").css('display', 'none');
     $("#imagem").click(function() {
         if($("#lista").is( ":visible" )){
             $("#lista").css('display', 'none');
         }else{
             $("#lista").css('display', 'block');
         }
       
       console.log('Visivel: ' + $("#lista").is( ":visible" ));
     });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Teste</title>
</head>
<body>

    <img src="../imagem.png" id="imagem"/>

    <ul id="lista">
    <li>Item de lista</li>
    </ul>

</body>
```

Veja outro exemplo abaixo funcionando, utilizando o método `toggle`:

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
         $("#lista").css('display', 'none');
         $("#imagem").click(function() {
             
            $( "#lista" ).toggle( 'display' );
             

         });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Teste</title>
</head>
<body>

    <img src="../imagem.png" id="imagem"/>

    <ul id="lista">
    <li>Item de lista</li>
    </ul>

</body>
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Valeu, cara, deu certo.

Comment: Fico feliz por ter ajudado, poderia marcar minha resposta com +1 ?